# `*this` outside member function body?

Tags: c++, c++11

In 5.1.1/3 of C++ standard [expr.prim.general]

> Unlike the object expression in other contexts, *this is not required to be of complete type for purposes
>   of class member access outside the member function body.  Only class members declared prior
>   to the declaration are visible.

And then this example:

```
struct A {
    char g();
    template<class T> auto f(T t) -> decltype(t + g()) 
    { return t + g(); }
};
template auto A::f(int t) -> decltype(t + g());
```

Can you explain the quote and the example? What exactly is being demonstrated here?

Comment: I believe it refers to the usage of `A::g` in the signature of `f` instead of its body. It complicate things for compiler writers, because you are asked to (potentially) perform overload resolution on `g()`, taking into account `A::g` thus, even though `A` is not completely defined. Prior to this, a typical thing was to first parse all declarations (of methods and members) and then use a "fully defined" `A` to parse the bodies of the methods.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Note that it is outside the function body.  You still have to defer the parsing of inline function bodies until after parsing a class specifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that you can access members via `this`, either explicitly or implicitly, outside function bodies within a class definition. At that point, the type is incomplete, and usually you can't access members of incomplete types.

But you can only do that within restricted parts of a member function declaration; the previous sentence says about `this`:

> It shall not appear before the optional *cv-qualifier-seq*

meaning that you can't use it in a parameter or leading return type specification. As far as I can see, the only place you can use it, outside a function body, is in a trailing return type.

You might need to do this when using `decltype` in a trailing return type, to get the type of an expression involving a non-static member. The example demonstrates this by implicitly using `this` to access `g()` in the trailing return type. It would have been more clear what was being demonstrated if it were written as `decltype(t + this->g())`.

Comment: Is that the only application?  `decltype` in a `trailing-return-type`? (or I guess in a parameter declaration as well)

Comment: @user1131467: I don't know. It's the only one I can immediately think of, but I'm not very imaginative on Mondays.

Comment: @user1131467: Not necessarily in trailing return type. You could use `decltype(this)` even when the return type is not trailing, or in a parameter declaration

Comment: @AndyProwl: You can only use the `decltype(this)` non-trailing inline inside a class specifier I think.  At namespace scope the parser won't know what class it is in yet.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Actually you can't; the sentence before this prevents you from using `this` except in a trailing return type. ("It shall not appear before the optional *cv-qualifier-seq*", where "It" means `this`).

Comment: So you can't use it in a parameter either.

Comment: @user1131467: I think not, and my compiler agrees (`invalid use of ‘this’ at top level`). I'm fairly sure now that it's only allowed for trailing return types.

Answer (score 6):

> What exactly is this an example of? Which statement is being demonstrated here?

The statement being demonstrated is that:

> Unlike the object expression in other contexts, *this is not required to be of complete type for purposes
>   of class member access (5.2.5) outside the member function body.

Outside the body of the member function there is an invocation to `g()`, which means `this->g()`. There, the type of `*this` (i.e. `A`) is not complete.

Per paragraph 9.2/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (3.9) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*.
>   Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies,
>   default arguments, and brace-or-equal-initializers for non-static data members (including such things in
>   nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.

Comment: Yes and the `trailing-return-type` is not on that list.

Comment: @user1131467: Right, so it is incomplete when doing `this->g()`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, all member access expressions are transformed by the compiler:

```
struct X{
  int a;
  void f(){}
  void g(int b){
    int x = a + b; // actually: int x = (*this).a + b
    f(); // actually: (*this).f();
  }
};
```

`§9.3.1 [class.mfct.non-static] p3`

> [...] the *id-expression* is transformed into a class member access expression (5.2.5) using `(*this)` (9.3.2) as the *postfix-expression* to the left of the `.` operator. [...]

Now, the example from the standard calls a member function outside of the body of another member function, in the trailing-return-type. And that call is transformed too:

```
template<class T> auto f(T t) -> decltype(t + (*this).g()) 
{ return t + (*this).g(); }
```

And outside of a member function body, `*this` is obviously an incomplete type. This means that you can only access the names that have been declared prior to the usage - but that part does not apply only to the `*this` usage:

```
struct X{
  using typeA = int;
  typeA f(); // OK, 'typeA' has been declared before

  typeB g(); // Error: 'typeB' not declared before usage
  using typeB = float;
};
```

Comment: I think it is incomplete in the inline definition of `A::f` inside the class specifier, however I think it is complete in the declaration of `A::f` that follows the closing brace.

Comment: Inside the body of a member function definition, `*this` is always considered a complete type, see `§9.2/2`.

Comment: Yes but the trailing return type is not part of the function body.

Comment: Erm, yeah, as I said, `*this` is incomplete in the trailing-return-type (I formulated it as "outside the function body").

Comment: Right, but in the trailing return type of a function declaration _following_ the closing brace of the class specifier (outside of it) `*this` is complete.

Comment: Ah, you were referring to inline vs out-of-class definitions. Nvm then.